# Java ReCaptcha Error: recaptcha-not-reachable on Solaris 10

Tags: recaptcha, solaris-10

I have a java webapps that runs ReCaptcha anti bot spam on one of the registration form request. It works fine on my development local machine, however, when i deployed it on my client's Solaris 10 server, it all went south. it throws this error message "recaptcha-not-reachable"

Found this solution on the net, and it gave me a little insight on what's going on :

https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/wiki/FirewallsAndRecaptcha

But the question is, how do i allow outbound access to all IPs on port 80 or use a proxy server to do access control based on host name in Solaris 10 ? I have very little knowledge on Solaris Firewall rules management. I have been searching up and low, but still unable to find a clear tutorial on how to do it.

Does Anybody has similar experience ? need your opinion on this ! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

checked with my network guy, and outbound communication port 80 is not blocked whatsoever.

my ipfilter is not enabled as well.

So Tried to ping google.com, but it still failed. So i suspect the problem lies on my machine domain name resolver server.

So i looked vi /etc/resolv.conf, I got it working by using www.OpenDNS.com DNS IP.